# PHP validation on forms

Tags: php, validation

I've five fields in the form

When a form is submitted and if three fields are not filled,it should validate and show errors on those three fields.

I used to do it using if loops,this will show one error at a time,instead, I want to show all the errors.

I want to check special characters,empty validation,min and max characters on each field.

```
      preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i', $category
```

How to check them all at once using PHP?

**Update**

```
 $errors = array();
 $required = array("Name", "Email");  
  foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
   {
     if(!empty($value))
       {
           $$key = $value;
      }
     else
      {
     if(in_array($key, $required))
     {
         array_push($errors, $key);
     }
    }        

   }
```

This can be used to check empty validation for all fiedls,how do i check for special characters,alpha numeric characters,the provblem would be each field will have different regex.
For eg: phone number and email can not have same regex.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well you can use loop and put the errors into array and then display to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$errors = array();
if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i', $name)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter valid name.";
}

if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i', $category)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter valid category.";
}

if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i', $amount)) {
    $errors[] = "Please enter valid amount.";
}

if(!empty($errors))
{
    echo "The was an error filling out the form:<br><ul>";
    foreach($errors as $msg)
    {
        echo "<li>$msg</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>Please try again.";
}
```

Or, to make it more concise, use something like [Ananth's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11048382/563460)

```
// your 3 fields that need to be validated; Key is field, Value is error message if check invalid.
$validate = array("name" => "Please enter valid name.", "category" => "Please enter a real category.", "amount" => "Please enter an amount.");

$error = array();
foreach ($validate as $field => $message) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i', $$field)) {
        $error[] = $message;
    }
}

if(!empty($errors))
{
    echo "The was an error filling out the form:<br><ul>";
    foreach($errors as $msg)
    {
        echo "<li>$msg</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>Please try again.";
}
```

**UPDATE**

Seeing as how each check has it's on regex, the first example is easy enough to solve. As for the second example, it only requires a small change.

```
// your 3 fields that need to be validated; 
// Key is Regex, value is array with the variable name (without the $) as the key, 
// and the error message as the value.

$validate = array(
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("name" => "Please enter valid name."), 
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("category" => "Please enter a real category."),
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("amount" => "Please enter an amount.")
);

$error = array(); // Empty array to store errors in.


foreach ($validate as $regex => $data) {  // Key = $regex, Value = array($variable, $error)
    if (preg_match($regex, ${$data[0]})) { // This code is untested, so try it without the braces around $data[0]
        $error[] = $data[1]; // If the data matches the regular expression provided, add the provided error message to the $error array.
    }
}

if(!empty($errors)) // If the $errors array isn't empty (has an error in it)
{
    echo "The was an error filling out the form:<br><ul>";
    foreach($errors as $msg) // Goes through each error, printing it to an unordered list.
    {
        echo "<li>$msg</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>Please try again.";
}
```

Note than in the above example, each has the same example regex, but it's simple enough to change those to your needs.

**EDIT**
All the code above is untested, though it should work, if it doesn't, try removing the braces around `$data[0]`, as mentioned in the accompanying comments.

**UPDATE 2**
If you need to add an optional checker, the same code can be modified slightly, with an extra `foreach` loop, for all the optional fields to check.

```
// your 3 fields that need to be validated; 
// Key is Regex, value is array with the variable name (without the $) as the key, 
// and the error message as the value.

$required = array(
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("name" => "Please enter valid name."), 
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("category" => "Please enter a real category."),
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("amount" => "Please enter an amount.")
);

$optional = array(
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("shipping" => "Please enter valid shipping location."), 
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("options" => "Please enter an clean option.")
);

$error = array(); // Empty array to store errors in.


foreach ($required as $regex => $data) {  // Key = $regex, Value = array($variable, $error)
    if (preg_match($regex, $$data[0])) { // This code is untested, so try it with or without the braces around $data[0]
        $error[] = $data[1]; // If the data matches the regular expression provided, add the provided error message to the $error array.
    }
}

foreach($optional as $regex => $data)
{
    if(strlen(trim($$data[0])) > 0) // If the trimmed length of the string (all leading and trailing whitespace removed) == 0?
    {
        if (preg_match($regex, $$data[0])) { // This code is untested, so try it with or without the braces around $data[0]
            $error[] = $data[1]; // If the data matches the regular expression provided, add the provided error message to the $error array.
    }
}

if(!empty($errors)) // If the $errors array isn't empty (has an error in it)
{
    echo "The was an error filling out the form:<br><ul>";
    foreach($errors as $msg) // Goes through each error, printing it to an unordered list.
    {
        echo "<li>$msg</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>Please try again.";
}
```

Comment: :Each field has different regex.

Comment: Be sure to mark an answer as correct if it works for you, and upvote constructive and useful answers.

Comment: :I'm getting data from previous page,Here i use $name =$_REQUEST['fieldname']; I can pass $name in $validate = array(
    '/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i' => array("$name" => "Please enter valid name."));

Comment: :In update,can you explain the for loop.Code is also not working.

Comment: @user1415759, read updated post for validating optional fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
$validate = array("name", "category", "amount"); // your 3 fields that need to be validated

$error = '';
foreach ($validate as $field) {
    if (preg_match('/^[a-z\d ]{3,20}$/i', $$field)) {
        $error .= $field;
    }
}
```

Later, based on $error you can show your errors.

Comment: :Each field has different regex.

Comment: Then you can have another array of the regex exps, and loop through them simultaneously.

Comment: :For eg:Some fields are not mandatory but if there is data,it has to be validated.How to check empty data validation.Can you put all this together in a piece of code.